# Siddhi - How to generate a JSON string

Tags: json, siddhi

I'm trying to generate a JSON string by combining various columns and save the JSON into Postgres table having JSON datatype. From the [documentation](https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-execution-json/api/1.1.0/#getstring-function), it is clear about reading feom JSON string.

```
define stream InputStream(json string);
from InputStream
select json:getString(json,"$.name") as name
insert into OutputStream;
```

But can we build the JSON in-flight and insert into table? Something like...

```
select '{"myname":json:getString(json,"$.name")}' as nameJSON
insert into postgresDB
```

Where nameJSON will be a JSON datatype in Postgres.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use, JSON:setElement to create a JSON from the attributes

```
from OutputStream
select json:setElement("{}", "$", json:getString(json,"$.name"), "myname") as value
insert into TempStream;
```

Comment: Thanks very much, as suggested earlier will take the discussion further on Github.